# JavaScript forEach statement differences when argument is before or in the brackets?

Tags: javascript

I came across this method in JavaScript but is wondering why the 2 blocks of code makes a difference. Why when I put A before the forEach, it works and when I pass it as an argument it doesn't work anymore?

```
function test(A) {

    var str = '';

    /* block 1 */
    A.forEach(function(element){
        str += element;
    });

    /* block 2
    forEach(A,function(element){
        str += element;
    });
    */

    return str;  // returns 123 from block 1, but error for block 2

}

console.log(test([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: I learned forEach from this book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html               The example in the book really makes me think I can also do it like block 2. But it seems like it is wrong.

Comment: In the book they defined their own `forEach` function above the example where they used it as such.  If you do that it will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `foreach` statement in JavaScript. There is a [`.forEach` *method*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on arrays, but there is no global `forEach` function.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's just how JS works. `forEach` is a property (method) of an array. It's not a global function.